# ArrayList showing empty even after adding elements

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am populating my `ArrayList` after receiving data from my API and filling it in objects stored by the `ArrayList` but when I log the size of the `ArrayList` it shows up to be empty.

Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RequestQueue queue;
private static ArrayList<Team> teams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.homeRecyclerView);

    this.teams = new ArrayList<>();

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    TeamNamesAdapter teamNamesAdapter = new TeamNamesAdapter(teams);

    parseJSON();

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(teamNamesAdapter);

    Log.i("Info",String.valueOf(teams.size()));

}


private void parseJSON(){
    String url = "http://192.168.0.174:8080/team";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, response -> {

                try {

                    for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                        JSONObject teamDetails = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Team team = new Team();
                        team.setId(Long.parseLong(teamDetails.getString("id")));
                        team.setTeamName(teamDetails.getString("teamName"));
                        team.setTotalMatches(Long.parseLong(teamDetails.getString("totalMatches")));
                        team.setTotalWins(Long.parseLong(teamDetails.getString("totalWins")));

                        this.teams.add(team);
                        
                        Log.i("Info","Added team "+team.getTeamName()+" successfully");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, error -> Log.i("ERROR","Couldn't parse JSON"));

    queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}}
```

My API is working as I am able to log every team object that is being created but its not stored in list.

Comment: I'm not aware of JsonArrayRequest functions but, is it possible it is being executed async?

Comment: @DorianPavetić You right,  that's exactly execute in async and the line of `log team team size` will be show 0.

Comment: If that is the case, then you are printing size of your array BEFORE it is even filled with values, even if it seems likes its going to be executed in the order code is written. You should put your printing after for loop in your try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove `this.teams = new ArrayList<>();` and add the initialisaiton at the beginning, since it is static, `private static ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Thanks this worked. But the size is still showing 0 even though my recycler view is getting populated.

Comment: Glad it helped, `Log.i("Info",String.valueOf(teams.size()));` here you can directly print teams.size like `Log.i("Info",teams.size());`. Please accept answer and up vote if it solved your issue